# How to run multiple vertices in Vert.x?

Tags: java, maven, web, vert.x

I am new to Vert.x and I want to run multiple verticles through jar. I have two files, one is MyFirstVertice.java and it routes the path "/q1/*" and return something. The second is MySecondVertice.java which routes the path "/q2/*". The second vertice is deployed in the first vertice.

MyFirstVertice.java

```
public class MyFirstVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/q1/*").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();
        String Y = request.getParam("key");
        String cipherText = request.getParam("message");

        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();

        response.setChunked(true);
        response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
        response.write(Y + "\n");
        response.write(cipherText + "\n");
        response.end();

        vertx.deployVerticle(new MySecondVerticle(), stringAsyncResult -> {
            System.out.println("Second verticle is deployed successfully.");
        });
    });

    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, httpServerAsyncResult -> {
        if (httpServerAsyncResult.succeeded()) {
            fut.complete();
        } else {
            fut.fail(httpServerAsyncResult.cause());
        }
    });
}
```

}

MySecondVetice.java

```
public class MySecondVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/q2/*").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.setChunked(true);
        response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

        response.end("q2");
    });

    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, httpServerAsyncResult -> {
        if (httpServerAsyncResult.succeeded()) {
            fut.complete();
        } else {
            fut.fail(httpServerAsyncResult.cause());
        }
    });
}
```

}

My pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Starter</Main-Class>
                                    <Main-Verticle>tutorial.diluo.MyFirstVerticle</Main-Verticle>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <artifactSet/>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I run it through `java -jar xxx-fat.jar`.

When I type localhost:8080/q1/xxx in the browser, it can return desired content. But when I am trying to visit localhost:8080/q2/xxx, it says "Resource Not Found". Can you tell me how to deploy two verticles that route different paths? I know that I can route different pathe in the same verticle, I just want to know how to deploy and run multiple vertices. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a bad design idea. You can have multiple routes on the same router, with different handlers. You really only need one Web Service Verticle, not two. You can use the Vert.x parameter "-instances #" to start multiple Verticles of the same Web Server Verticle if you wish to spread the load some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>The problem you have is that both `Verticles` are attempting to bind to the same port (`8080`) which you can't do. 
So the second `Verticle` is likely throwing a `BindException` and failing to come up. The first `Verticle` then, doesn't have a resource at `/q2` which is why you're getting the `Resource Not Found`.</strike>

Updated as per comment from tsegismont:

`Vert.x` allows multiple Verticles to start on the same port in a feature known as [server sharing](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_server_sharing). When this happens, `Vert.x` will use a round robin strategy to send requests to each `Verticle` in turn. So, you should see 50% of requests working for `/q1` and 50% of request for `/q2`. But - as noted by tsegismont, your browser uses `persistent connections` so it maintains a connection to a single `Verticle`. You should find that using curl, or another browser may give you a better result. Either way, this isn't probably what you want.

You should have a think if you need 2 `Verticles`. Generally you want to think of a `Verticle` as an entry point in to your application - it's a way of `bootstrapping` your application / microservice.

If you really need 2 `Verticles` then you will have to choose separate ports or run on separate boxes. If you don't, then just create 2 `routes` on the same `router`.

See http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/ for more info on `Vert.x Web`

Comment: Actually, if two verticles start a server for the same port, the traffic will be load balanced between them. No `BindException`. The reason why @di-luo doesn't see anything after the first request is that browsers use persistent connections so the traffic still goes to the first verticle. If you do the same with curl, you should see one half of the requests failing with 404, the other half reaching the second verticle. Other than that your answer looks good to me.

Comment: @tsegismont Yes you're very correct - my mistake. I've only ever taken advantage of the load balancing by starting the same `Verticle` multiple times, so didn't think about it. I shall update my answer accordingly

Comment: @tsegismont hallucinated the same problem for over an hour, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For clarification, note that Vertx documentation may be misleading in some cases and has been a point of confusion in many posts and many websites. The documentation states that multiple verticals may run on the same port. This apparently does not mean that two verticals with two separate purposes may listen to the same port. I.E. if the first vertical is listening for "\hello" and the second vertical is listening for "\world" then this is an incorrect set up. Somehow this is lost in the translation from "multiple verticals listening to the same port are possible" when the meaning is that "Multiple objects/instantiations of the same vertical can be run on the same port."

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to achieve, but even so, you can't run two HTTP servers bound to the same port — or virtually anything.

You need to declare different ports for your approach, or —and this is the approach I like most- have only one HTTP server and "spawn multiple instances" of it. You can read more about it [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_scaling_sharing_tcp_servers).

For your case, you can safely delete `MySecondVetice.java`; update `MyFirstVertice.java` and include the `/q2/*` endpoint (and handlers for it). Then, you need to do some modification(s) when you deploy it (you don't have the code that deploys `MyFirstVertice.java` so I'll "improvise" in that matter:

```
@Slf4j
public final class Application extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  public void start(final Future<Void> startFuture) {
    deploy(MyFirstVertice.class, new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(4));
    LOGGER.info("Module(s) and/or verticle(s) deployment...DONE");
    //startFuture.complete();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop(final Future<Void> stopFuture) {
    LOGGER.debug("Undeploying verticle(s)...DONE");
    LOGGER.info("Application stopped successfully. Enjoy the elevator music while we're offline...");
    stopFuture.complete();
  }

  private void deploy(final Class<? extends AbstractVerticle> clazz, final DeploymentOptions options) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(clazz.getName(), options, handler -> {
      if (handler.succeeded()) {
        LOGGER.debug("{} started successfully (deployment identifier: {})", clazz.getSimpleName(), handler.result());
      } else {
        LOGGER.error("{} deployment failed due to: ", clazz.getSimpleName(), handler.cause());
        //stop();
      }
    });
  }
}
```