# Vertx verticles on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nginx, continuous-integration, vert.x

I created Vertx application which contains 2 verticles. 1 is running on port 8888 and the other is running on 8881.

I am trying to deploy the application on Elastic beanstalk. But I'm getting error 502 Bad Gateway.

Here's the config file nginx place at `.ebextensions/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    33282;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  include       conf.d/*.conf;

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default     "upgrade";
  }

  server {
      listen        5000;
      root /var/app/current/public;

      location / {
      }

      location /api {
          proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8888;
          proxy_http_version  1.1;

          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      location /api2 {
          proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8881;
          proxy_http_version  1.1;

          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

      client_header_timeout 60;
      client_body_timeout   60;
      keepalive_timeout     60;
      gzip                  off;
      gzip_comp_level       4;

      # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
      include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf;
      include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf;
  }
}
```

Here's the CodeBuild `buildspec.yml` file:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on 'date'
      - gradle bootJar
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on 'date'
      - ls build/libs
      - mv build/libs/*.jar app.jar
      - ls
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.jar
    - .ebextensions/**/*
```

I have installed nginx on my local machine and with the above configuration it is working fine.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Abdullah, do you receive any errors? I mean, the verticles start properly? do you think that the problem is related to vert.x or nginx?

Comment: @jccampanero No errors. The verticles start properly. I can see the logs. I don't think the issue is with nginx or vert.x because I have the same setup on my local machine and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @AbdullahUmer. One thing I would try will be setting your nginx listen port to `80`, by default the application load balancer points to that port of the nginx server in the EC2 instance. In addition, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html), by default Beanstalk configures the nginx proxy to forward requests to your application on port `5000` while your vertices run on ports `8888` and `8881`. You can override the default port by setting the `PORT` ... see next

Comment: [environment property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html#java-se-options). The problem is the two ports... I honestly doesn't remember now, but at least usually Beanstalk only exposes one port to the outside world. Maybe you can try [running your verticles on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666482/how-to-run-multiple-vertices-in-vert-x), I do not know if it fill your needs.

Comment: @jccampanero Thanks for replying. I had set PORT in the env config for the elastic beanstalk but unfortunately it did not work. I'm assuming that the beanstalk container will forward the outside traffice to the PORT which is the same port nginx is listening.

Comment: but unfortunately its not working

Comment: You configured `PORT` to the value `8888`, is it right? `PORT` should point to where your app is listening. Please, be aware that as you are providing your custom nginx conf perhaps this config is unnecessary, but it is worth value to try it. Did you adjust the port in which nginx is listening from port `5000` to `80` in your custom `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Please, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477363/13942448), I think it can be of help in understand the full workflow.